# Why adnroidx recycler-view click not working when click it's item?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick

I'm trying to implement `RecyclerView` onclick listener, but it is not working. I've tried a lot, and try to implement other way too, but not working at all.

**My Main Class:**

```
public class MainMenuDashboard extends AppCompatActivity{

    private RecyclerView recyclerMenu;
    private RecyclerViewMenuAdapter menuAdapter;

    private Call<CategoryModel> categoryModelCall;
    private TokenManager tokenManagerMainMenu;
    private ApiService serviceMainMenu;
    List<CategoryModel.Subset> menuList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_dashboard);

        tokenManagerMainMenu = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
        serviceMainMenu = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManagerMainMenu);

        recyclerMenu = findViewById(R.id.recyclerMenu);

        menuList  = new ArrayList<>();
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainMenuDashboard.this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerMenu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        menuAdapter = new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(menuList);
        recyclerMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
        menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mainMenuDashBoardToolbar = findViewById(R.id.mainMenuDashBoardToolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mainMenuDashBoardToolbar);

        menuContent();      
    }

    private void menuContent() {

        categoryModelCall = serviceMainMenu.menuContent(incomingRoleId, true);

        categoryModelCall.enqueue(new Callback<CategoryModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<CategoryModel> call, @NotNull Response<CategoryModel> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null && response.code() != 400) {
                    //findViewById(R.id.shimmerCategory).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    CategoryModel categoryModel = response.body();
                    menuList = categoryModel.getSubset();
                    menuAdapter = new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(menuList);
                    recyclerMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
                    //menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    menuAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter.ClickListenerMenu() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(int position) {

                            Toast.makeText(MainMenuDashboard.this, "Position "+position+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });
                    menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else {

                    if (response.code() == 401) {
                        Intent i = new Intent(MainMenuDashboard.this, MainActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("USER_SESSION", true);
                        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        tokenManagerMainMenu.deleteToken();
                        startActivity(i);                        
                        finish();
                    }                   
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<CategoryModel> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {                
            }
        });
    } 
 }
```

**My Adapter:**

```
public class RecyclerViewMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewMenuAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "NotesRecyclerAdapter";

    private List<CategoryModel.Subset> subsetsCategories;
    private ClickListenerMenu mClickListener;
    private Context context;


    public RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(List<CategoryModel.Subset> subsetsCategories) {
        this.subsetsCategories = subsetsCategories;

    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_recycler_main_menu_category, parent, false);
        return new RecyclerViewHolder(view, mClickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        String menuCategoryImage = subsetsCategories.get(position).getIcon();
        Picasso.get().load(menuCategoryImage).placeholder(R.drawable.admin).into(viewHolder.menuThumb);

        String menuCategoryName = subsetsCategories.get(position).getName();
        viewHolder.menuName.setText(menuCategoryName);

        //Item click
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mClickListener.onClick(position);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Position "+position+" Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return subsetsCategories.size();
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView menuThumb;
        TextView menuName;
        private ClickListenerMenu mListener;
        //ClickListenerMenu clickListenerMenu;

        public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, ClickListenerMenu clickListenerMenu) {
            super(view);
            menuThumb = view.findViewById(R.id.menuThumb);
            menuName = view.findViewById(R.id.menuName);
            mListener = clickListenerMenu;

        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(ClickListenerMenu clickListener) {
        mClickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public interface ClickListenerMenu {
        void onClick(int position);
    }
}
```

**I still can't find where I did wrong!! Any insight will be very appreciated**

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

Add item click listener in your adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {

    String menuCategoryImage = subsetsCategories.get(position).getIcon();
    Picasso.get().load(menuCategoryImage).placeholder(R.drawable.admin).into(viewHolder.menuThumb);

    String menuCategoryName = subsetsCategories.get(position).getName();
    viewHolder.menuName.setText(menuCategoryName);

    //Item click
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        { 
            // Do something 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Initialise your recycler view outside and put this line `menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` where you add data in your list.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu_dashboard);

    tokenManagerMainMenu = TokenManager.getInstance(getSharedPreferences("prefs", MODE_PRIVATE));
    serviceMainMenu = RetrofitBuilder.createServiceWithAuth(ApiService.class, tokenManagerMainMenu);

    recyclerMenu = findViewById(R.id.recyclerMenu);

    menuList = new List<CategoryModel.Subset>();
    GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(MainMenuDashboard.this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerMenu.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    menuAdapter = new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(menuList);
    recyclerMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);
    menuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    menuContent();
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: I did this, but still not working: //Item click
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mClickListener.onClick(position);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

Comment: Try to change public RecyclerViewHolder(View view, final ClickListenerMenu clickListenerMenu) instead of your code may be it's help

Comment: No it's not giving any error, but showing No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: Why are you not initialised your recycler view outside?May be you are not getting response So,it's gave error.

Comment: Are you change View itemView to View view in your RecyclerViewHolder?

Comment: Yes I changed  View itemView to View view, Please see my update code

Comment: remove initialise recycler view inside of menuContent() and remove view.setOnClickListener

Comment: remove "menuAdapter = new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(menuList);
                    recyclerMenu.setAdapter(menuAdapter);" this lines

Comment: When I remove this two line from menuContent(), recycler-view not showing anything

Comment: So,may be you have not get any data from response.

Comment: Response is coming but, it is only inside onResponse method.

Comment: I solved it by removing android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true" from My model layout inside CardView. Thank you brother for your time and effort.

Comment: @AleefFaminn Most Welcom ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Add these line in the onBindViewHolder() method:

```
viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
//remove this lines
                            //mClickListener.onClick(position);
                            //notifyDataSetChanged();
//add this
           context.startActivity(new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class))              
                    }
                });
```

and in your MainMenuDashboard class, initialize your Adapter like this:

```
menuAdapter = new RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(this,menuList);
```

also change your Adapter constructor like this:

````
public RecyclerViewMenuAdapter(Context context,List<CategoryModel.Subset> subsetsCategories) {
        this.subsetsCategories = subsetsCategories;
        this.context = context;
}

    ```
````

Comment: clickListenerMenu and getAdapterPosition() method not working inside onBindViewHolder

Comment: I just copied your onClick() code, howerver you can do your onClick inside bindViewHolder() method, where the position parameter returns the position of your item in recyclerView

Comment: Ok, You need to implement the **ClickListenerMenu** interface on your **MainActivity** and override the interface method, thus you will get the position of item in your overridden method..

**And make sure that you call menuContent() mehod before initializing your adapter**

Comment: I have some question, if you don't mind please answer. I will try to help you.
1.Is your response is coming?
2. Is the response is showing on recycler view?
and 3. What you want to do, after clicking on item?

Comment: 1. yes response is coming, 2. yes the response is showing on recycler view, 3. I want  to navigate to other activity that I can load  child menu (as permission given on incoming rest api json response), Basically I'm building a dynamic dashboard menu.

Comment: I have edited my answer, try this, and let me know what happens..

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: Does it show any error??, Have you removed the interface?

Comment: Everything is fine just not Listen to the click

Comment: I solved it by removing android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true" from My model layout inside CardView. Thank you brother for your time and effort.